# what's the difference between jquery onchange and dom onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's the difference between jquery onchange

```
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery('body').on('change','#idtext',function(){
        $("#result").load("result.php?id="+$(this).val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

and dom onchange

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("idtext").onchange = function(){
        jQuery(function($) {
            $("#result").load("result.php?id="+$(this).val());
        });
        return false;
    };
};
```

Comment: The first one has bound event with event - delegation and the second one is normal event binding with plain javascript..

Comment: Those two aren't even close to being the same. You'd have to use addEventListener, and rely on bubbling etc. to make it delegated if you're going to make the plain JS version do the same thing.

Comment: Can you tell me that results the same?

Comment: which one is faster between two above ?

Comment: Both methods are different and you need to choose one for the case you need, and think pure js is always faster.

Comment: No, performance wise they are not the same. According to this jsperf test, native javascript will run much faster.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-js-onchange